# How to scroll to specific element in jQuery DataTable programatically?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a paginated jQuery DataTable that I would like to scroll to a specific row. This row may be on another page. I am currently trying the following:

```
var scroller = profileTable.fnSettings().nTable.parentNode;                                              
scroller.scrollTo( $('.row_selected'), 1 );
```

where `profileTable` is a DataTable.

The row I would like to scroll to has a `<tr class="row_selected">`.

The Javascript error I am seeing in Chrome's Developer Tools is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'scrollTo'
```

I also tried

```
var scroller = profileTable.fnSettings().nTable.parentNode;                                              
$(scroller).scrollTo( $('.row_selected'), 1 );
```

with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object]> has no method 'scrollTo'
```

I've tried the [ScrollTo Plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)
with no luck. Anybody using this plugin with jQuery 1.7.2 or higher?

Any examples of moving to a specified row in a DataTable would be appreciated.

Comment: If it has no method scrollTo, you either didn't have it on the page or accidentally nuked it later on.

Comment: What is the problem with ScrollTo plugin?

Comment: Also - looks like you want to scroll some scrollable div (.parentNode). Does it has a scroll bars? Or you want to put selected row at the top of window?

Comment: @Fangel, not at my desk right now but it has something to do with not getting "slice" of unknown in the jquery.scrollTo-min.js file.

Comment: One problem I am seeing is that the row that has class "row_selected" is not in the DOM. It is in the HTML though. But since the DataTable is not displaying it I believe it is removed from the DOM. Guess I'll have to post another question on how to use jQuery to select an item not in the DOM.

Comment: The fnDisplayRow() is the solution. 
see [an answer to a similar question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17961164

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!profileTable.find($("tr.row_selected"))[0]){
    profileTable.fnPageChange( 'next' );
}
$(".dataTables_scrollBody").scrollTop( $("tr.row_selected").offset().top - $(".dataTables_scrollBody").height() );
```

You have to paginate to find the page which have the selected row and after that scroll to it.